# Spring MongoDB Criteria update

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo

How can I write the query to update the "contacts.collection.value._class = SubClass2" and set the value to xyz with Spring Mongodb Criteria?

```
{ "_class" : "MyClass",
  "_id" : ObjectId( "51ecc95503644e4489bb742e" ),
  "contacts" : [ 
    { "property1" : "Value1",
      "property2" : "Value2",
      "collection" : [ 
        { "value" : "1",
          "_class" : "SubClass1" }, 
        { "value" : "2",
          "_class" : "SubClass2" }, 
        { "value" : "2",
          "_class" : "SubClass3" },
```

I am trying to do this with Spring Data Mongo Criteria class.

So far I got this but it's not working

```
            query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(myClassId)
                    .and("contacts.collection.value").is("2")
                    .and("contacts.collection._class").is("SubClass2"));
            update.set("contacts.collection.$.value", "3");
            mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, MyClass.class);
```

I'm getting this error;

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property value found on ...!

Notes:

1. The "contacts" collection is a list of some interface.
2. I sanitized the variable names and class names.
3. If you don't know how to do it with Criteria, please give me the java code.

Thanks

Adding stacktrace

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property xyz found on com.blah.SomeInterface!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:225) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getPath(QueryMapper.java:202) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getTargetProperty(QueryMapper.java:190) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:86) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:925) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$11.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:920) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doUpdate(MongoTemplate.java:920) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.updateFirst(MongoTemplate.java:902) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Based on Jayz's answer, I wrote the update with RoboMongo and it works updates the query result!

```
db.myDB.update(
{
"_id":ObjectId("51ecc95503644e4489bb742e"),
"contacts.collection._class": "SubClass1",
"contacts.collection.value": "1",
},
{ 
    $set: { 'contacts.0.collection.$.value': '3' } 
},
{ getLastError: 1 });
```

But when I try to do it with mongoTemplate nothing is updated.

Comment: Could you please post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

query will get you the index of the collection array which matches query criteria. With your data structure, you need two array indexes, one for contacts and one for collection, which is not possible (as far as I know). You need to know the position of either the contacts array item or the collection array item. Let's assume you know the position of the contacts array item. if it is 0th position, here is your complete query:

```
query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("_id").is(myClassId),
        Criteria.where("contacts.collection.value").is("2"),
        Criteria.where("contacts.collection._class").is("SubClass2"));
        update.set("contacts.0.collection.$.value", "3");
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jayz 
This is the correct query, but update is not working contacts is a collection also collection is a collection. So how do I specify the value that is inside the collection of another collection?

Below doesn't work
- contacts.collection.$.value
Also tried
- contacts.0.collection.$.value
Doesn't work either

Comment: unfortunately doesn't update anything. I added WriteResult to see the outcome getN() is 0 and result.getLastError().getErrorMessage() is null.

Comment: did you check the array index of the contacts collection you want to update? I created a test class, created the whole document, checked (in the mongo shell) the array index of contacts for which collection collection has to be updated was 0, then ran the query using the test class and it worked. the value in subdocument (collection collection) was updated. for your case, assuming you have exactly the same document you have given here, the array index is 1, so use: update.set("contacts.1.collection.$.value", "3");

Comment: I have been able to resolve this by using the exact indexes on both collections. I was expecting that I could write the update query without providing such information but seems like its not possible as of now. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: I am sure you can avoid passing exact index on one collection by using the correct Criteria. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The filtered positional operator $ identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation.

> query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
>           Criteria.where("_id").is(myClassId),
>           Criteria.where("contacts.collection.value").is("2"),
>           Criteria.where("contacts.collection._class").is("SubClass2"));
>           update.set("contacts.$.collection.$.value", newValueToUpdate in perticular position);
>           mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, MyClass.class);